# Terraform provision Elastic beanstalk with aws:elbv2:listener:listener_port not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to setup the additional listener on my Elastic Beanstalk Environment's ALB (Application Load Balancer). I followed the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbv2-listener) to add below configuration settings and its attributes, but when run `terraform apply` i kept getting error `InvalidParameterValue: Invalid Listener Port (NaN): listener_port`

```
additional_alb_listener_settings_https = [{ 
 description = "HTTPS Listener for ALB" 
 protocol = "HTTPS" 
 ssl_certificate_arn = "xxxxxxxxx" 
 ssl_policy = "xxxxxxxxx" 
}] 

variable "additional_alb_listener_settings" {
  description = "additional listener settings in addition to default port 80"
  type = list(object({
    description         = string
    protocol            = string
    ssl_certificate_arn = string
    ssl_policy          = string
  }))
  default = []

}

  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.additional_alb_listener_settings
    content {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:listener_port"
      name      = "Protocol"
      value     = setting.value.protocol
    }
  }
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.additional_alb_listener_settings
    content {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:listener_port"
      name      = "SSLCertificateArns"
      value     = setting.value.ssl_certificate_arn
    }
  }

  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.additional_alb_listener_settings
    content {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:listener_port"
      name      = "SSLPolicy"
      value     = setting.value.ssl_policy
    }
  }
```

However according the aws:elbv2:listener:listener_port on AWS documentation, it does not ask for `port` attribute. What am I missing here

Comment: What is the FULL error message?

Comment: @Marcin 
InvalidParameterValue: Invalid Listener Port (NaN): listener_port status code: 400, request id:xxxxxx
with module.eb_env_staging.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.eb_env["env"],
│   on ../modules/elasticbeanstalk/main.tf line 34, in resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "eb_env":
│   34: resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "eb_env" {